# jquery not working/editor adding symbols

Tags: jquery, toggle, text-editor, symbols, jsfiddle

This is two questions in one, so here we go.

I have a simple code that I got from jsfiddle (at http://jsfiddle.net/tedp/aL7Xe/1/)

But it it doesn't call the jquery function when I put it in my website (live demo at http://beattrack.net/test.php#).

Also, it is adding some funny symbols to the end of it. Is that my fault or my text editor's? I am using textwrangler--saving as UTF-8. When I try to save to ISO Latin 9, it says there are unnamable characters--it's happening on more than just this one webpage. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    #menucontainer {
        display:none;
    }​
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
  $('html').click(function() {
     $('#menucontainer').hide(); 
  });

  $('#menuwrap').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('#menutoggle').click(function(event){
     $('#menucontainer').toggle();
  });
</script>
</head> 

<body>
 <div id="menuwrap">
  <a href="#" id="menutoggle">Menu Toggle</a>
  <ul id="menucontainer">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>​

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"` attribute from the script tag, and that should work. Make a new script tag for jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('html').click(function() {
     $('#menucontainer').hide(); 
  });

  $('#menuwrap').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('#menutoggle').click(function(event){
     $('#menucontainer').toggle();
  });
</script>
```

Also, put the second  element at the end of the .

As for the strange characters, try using an HTTP header in your PHP code to specify that the page is in UTF-8. My browser is saying that the encoding for you page is ISO-8859-1, hence the strange characters.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

Comment: awesome. the header worked like a charm to get rid of the symbols. thank you. However, I made a new script tag, but it still isn't working...

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

Comment: Could you update it on the link you gave above so I can try to see what's the matter? Because I just went there again, and it's not showing a new script tag.

Comment: changed the tag to what you posted, and still nothing. Is there an onload jquery function that I am missing or something? I updated above to reflect what I have now... Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah I see what you did. No this is *not* what I meant. Make a new script tag altogether. I'm going to update my answer, give me a sec.

Comment: Check my answer. And I was mistaken about the extra "/". I removed it. Use "</script" instead.

Comment: Oh, awesome! I understand that, now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Like I said: use "</script>" instead. Try that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12415/discussion-between-mr-musicman-and-hassan)